# Android custom ratingbar with dynamic numstar and custom icon behaving weird on click

Tags: java, android, rating, ratingbar

I am trying to create a custom rating bar where number of stars is dynamic and the drawable that I need to use also depends on the type, that I get from server.
I am doing this -

```
<RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:id="@+id/rating_bar_star"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/RatingBarStar"
            android:stepSize="0.1"/>
```

then I added this in style -

```
<style name="RatingBarStar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    </style>
```

this is my rating_bar.xml I added in drawable -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

rating_bar_empty.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_off" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_off" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_off" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/rating_off" />
```

and rating_bar_filled.xml -

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_on" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_on" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_on" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/rating_on" />
```

and then added this in my java file -

```
rating_bar_star.setNumStars(getStars());
```

Obviously I am getting stars from server. Now my problem is when I click/select a star it doesn't select one whole star. 
If number of star is 6 and I set stepSize as 0.8 then it works fine but same stepSize doesn't work for 10 stars. All I want, my stars to show selected appearance for selected stars.

this is what I get when I don't set stepSize and select/click on first star

[image: this is what I get when I don't set stepSize and select/click on first star]

and this when I click on second -

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set stepsize 1??

Comment: @UpendraShah Yes tried that. It highlights 1 and a half star when I select one